# Asp.net Mvc ajax action submitting twic

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am submitting data via ajax with post url but this action in controller exciting more than one time like triple time I am using parent view in main view by

```
@Html.Action("Driverview", "Driver")
```

here is my code for main view

```
<div class="modal fade" id="driver_vehicle" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="driver_vehicle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal_driver_vehicle" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="tab_header">
            <div class="drivers_tab selected">Drivers <span class="addition">+</span></div>
            <div class="vehicles_tab">Vehicles <span class="addition">+</span></div>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <!-- if there is too much content then add this class to scroll <div class="modal-body scrollbar"> -->
        <div class="modal-body">


            @Html.Action("Driverview", "Driver")
            @Html.Action("Vehicleview", "Vehicle")

         @*@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Vehicle/Vehicleview.cshtml");}*@   




        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my ajax code for post

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
        var Driverpic = $('.avatar').val();
        var drivername = $('.DriverName').val();
        var DriverEmail = $('.DriverEmail').val();
        var StartTime = $('.StartTime').val();
        var WorkingHours = $('.WorkingHours').val();
        var LunchPeriod = $('.LunchPeriod').val();
        var DriverIsActive = $('.DriverIsActive').val();

        var postdata = {
            Driverpic: Driverpic,
            DriverName: drivername,
            DriverEmail: DriverEmail,
            StartTime: StartTime,
            WorkingHours: WorkingHours,
            LunchPeriod: LunchPeriod,
            DriverIsActive: DriverIsActive
        }
        if (drivername != "" && DriverEmail != "" && StartTime != "" && WorkingHours != "" && LunchPeriod != "" & DriverIsActive != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Driver/Driverview/',
                type: 'POST', // use Get for [HttpGet] action or POST for [HttpPost]
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('.dirveraddform').each(function () {
                        this.reset();
                    });
                    $(".select2").val('').trigger('change');
                }
            });
        }
        (e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
       }
    });
```

Controller for Driverview

```
public class DriverController : Controller
{
    /*public ActionResult Driverview()
    {
        return View();
    }*/

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Driverview(DriverViewModel driverdata)
    {
        // Data from submited form for add driver
        DriverViewModel ddata = new DriverViewModel
        {
            DriverName = driverdata.DriverName,
            DriverEmail = driverdata.DriverEmail,
            StartTime = driverdata.StartTime,
            WorkingHours = driverdata.WorkingHours,
            LunchPeriod = driverdata.LunchPeriod,
            DriverIsActive = driverdata.DriverIsActive
        };

        // Please Write your database code here

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Drivers(Name, Email, StartTime, WorkingHours, LunchPeriodStartTime, IsActive) VALUES(@Name, @Email, @StartTime, @WorkingHours, @LunchPeriod, @DriverIsActive)";
            query += " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", driverdata.DriverName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", driverdata.DriverEmail);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", driverdata.StartTime);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkingHours", driverdata.WorkingHours);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LunchPeriod", driverdata.LunchPeriod);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DriverIsActive", driverdata.DriverIsActive);
                // customer.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
            }
        }


        return Json(ddata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
```

Help me please

Comment: due to the way you've written your JS event handler, it will execute every time you press the Enter or Return key anywhere on your page (assuming also of course that the fields mentioned in your `if` statement have got at least 1 character in them each). Was that your intention? You didn't make clear what it _should_ do instead. I would have thought it would make more sense to trigger this on a button click, so the user can press the button (or trigger the same event by pressing enter when focused on that form/button) once they've finished entering all the relevant information?

Comment: In other words, just use a normal form submit process, like every other HTML form in the world, but intercept it with JS, prevent the default postback and make it use AJAX instead. The keypress event approach is a bit unusual and I'd guess it's probably the source of your issue.